# android : TabHost Gravity isn't work

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

i create a TabHost by XML and invoke it in an Activity using findViewByID().
i put the gravity of tabhost and tabwidget to be right but it isn't work, how can i make it work ?

Note : i invoked this Xml layout in Activity not in TabActivity

Here is the xml file of layout, Thanks in Advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="right" android:foregroundGravity="right" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/submenu_bg" android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_secondary_tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `android:gravity="right"`. Just include this together with **layout_gravity** and see if it works

Comment: where should i use it, as there is no android:gravity in tabhost but there is android:layout_gravity